# how to read value from string.xml in android?

Tags: android, string, layout

I have written the line:

```
String Mess = R.string.mess_1 ;
```

to get string value, but instead of returning string, it is giving me id of type integer. How can I get its string value? I mentioned the string value in the `string.xml` file.

Answer (score 883, accepted):

Try this

```
String mess = getResources().getString(R.string.mess_1);
```

**UPDATE**

```
String string = getString(R.string.hello);
```

You can use either `getString(int)` or `getText(int)` to retrieve a string. `getText(int)` will retain any rich text styling applied to the string.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Comment: you can simplify that to `this.getString(R.string.some_id)` if you're already in a `Context` (Activity or Service).

Comment: I used this: String message += getResources().getString(R.string.string1) + "some more word..."; and I wanted to send this string via sms, but it is not working. It works fine without the string resource. Am I missing something?

Comment: You can simplify that even further to getString(R.string.some_id). And if you want to customize the string, you can make the string something like "Welcome, %1$s", then you can use getString(R.string.some_id, "John Doe"). to get "Welcome, John Doe" at runtime.

Comment: Also works for other types like I just used `getResouces().getInteger(R.integer.my_value_in_xml)`

Answer (score 67):

In Activity:

```
this.getString(R.string.resource_name)
```

If not in activity but have access to context:

```
context.getString(R.string.resource_name)
application.getString(R.string.resource_name)
```

Comment: You don't have to include `this` while you are in Activity. Simply `getString()` will let you do things.

Answer (score 46):

I'm using this:

```
String URL = Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.mess_1);
```

Comment: Warning - according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8864116/3836051) quoting android's documentation, using `Resources.getSystem()` does not give you the application resources, but only android's. It should not be used for resources like `string`. I used this solution and the application crashed, throwing a `notfoundexception` that was hard to understand (as the resource exists in `strings.xml`).

Answer (score 26):

By the way, it is also possible to create string arrays in the strings.xml like so:

```
<string-array name="tabs_names"> 
    <item>My Tab 1</item> 
    <item>My Tab 2</item>
</string-array>
```

And then from your Activity you can get the reference like so:

```
String[] tab_names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tab_names);
String tabname1=tab_names[0];//"My Tab 1"
```

Comment: This answer should be up there.Most of the time, you are reading arrays from XML not single strings.

Answer (score 11):

Only for future references.

In the [String resources documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) it says:

> You can use either getString(int) or getText(int) to retrieve a string. getText(int) will >retain any rich text styling applied to the string.

Answer (score 6):

Solution 1

```
Context context;
String mess = context.getString(R.string.mess_1)
```

Solution 2

```
String mess = getString(R.string.mess_1)
```

Answer (score 3):

In fragments, you can use

```
getActivity().getString(R.id.whatever);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add the string value to a button for example, simple use

```
android:text="@string/NameOfTheString"
```

The defined text in *strings.xml* looks like this:

```
 <string name="NameOfTheString">Test string</string>
```

Answer (score 3):

### Details

- Android Studio 3.1.4
- Kotlin version: 1.2.60

### Task

- single line use
- minimum code
- use suggestions from the compiler

### Step 1. Application()

> Get link to the context of you application

```
class MY_APPLICATION_NAME: Application() {

    companion object {
        private lateinit var instance: MY_APPLICATION_NAME

        fun getAppContext(): Context = instance.applicationContext
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        instance = this
        super.onCreate()
    }

}
```

### Step 2. Add int extension

```
inline fun Int.toLocalizedString(): String = MY_APPLICATION_NAME.getAppContext().resources.getString(this)
```

### Usage

> strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <!-- .......  -->
    <string name="no_internet_connection">No internet connection</string>
    <!-- .......  -->
</resources>
```

> Get string value:

```
val errorMessage = R.string.no_internet_connection.toLocalizedString()
```

### Results

[image]
[image]

Comment: Cool answer there.
can you give me some advice to improve on kotlin, android.
any good resources, routines that you can please recommend

Answer (score 3):

You can read directly the value defined into strings.xml:

```
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello StackOverflow!</string>
</resources>
```

and set into a variable:

```
String mymessage = getString(R.string.hello);
```

but we can define the string into the view:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You must reference Context name before using `getResources()` in Android.

```
String user=getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.muser);
```

OR

```
Context mcontext=getApplicationContext();

String user=mcontext.getResources().getString(R.string.muser);
```

Answer (score 1):

while u write `R`. you are referring to the `R.java` class created by eclipse, use `getResources().getString()` and pass the `id` of the resource from which you are trying to read inside the `getString()` method.

**Example :** `String[] yourStringArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Your_array);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
 getText(R.string.mess_1);
```

> Basically, you need to pass the resource id as a parameter to the getText() method.

Answer (score 1):

**If you are in an activity you can use**

```
getResources().getString(R.string.whatever_string_youWant);
```

**If you are not in an Activity 
use this :**

```
getApplicationContext.getResource().getString(R.String.Whatever_String_you_want)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Jetpack Compose, you can use

```
stringResource(R.string.yourstring)
```

Answer (score 0):

**

> I hope this code is beneficial

**

```
String user = getResources().getString(R.string.muser);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

- You can use `getString(R.string.some_string_id)` in both **`Activity`** or **`Fragment`**.
- You can use `Context.getString(R.string.some_string_id)` where you don't have direct access to `getString()` method. Like `Dialog`.

**Problem** is where **you don't have `Context` access**, like a method in your `Util` class.

Assume below method without Context.

```
public void someMethod(){
    ...
    // can't use getResource() or getString() without Context.
}
```

Now you will pass `Context` as a parameter in this method and use `getString().`

```
public void someMethod(Context context){
    ...
    context.getString(R.string.some_id);
}
```

**What i do is**

```
public void someMethod(){
    ...
    App.getRes().getString(R.string.some_id)
}
```

**What? It is very simple to use anywhere in your app!**

So here is a **Bonus unique solution** by which you can access resources from anywhere like `Util class` .

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.res.Resources;

public class App extends Application {
    private static App mInstance;
    private static Resources res;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
        res = getResources();
    }

    public static App getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public static Resources getResourses() {
        return res;
    }

}
```

Add name field to your `manifest.xml` `<application` tag.

```
<application
        android:name=".App"
        ...
        >
        ...
    </application>
```

Now you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

getString(R.string.your_string) get the result

Answer (score 0):

`String myString = getResources().getString(R.string.here_your_string_name);`

Now your string is copied into myString. I hope it will work for you.