# Sectionpager title from string resources

Tags: java, android

I have a `sectionpager` in my app and want to load its title from string resources, to support different language titles.
That's my `sectionpager` class:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        Auftrag fragmenttab1 = new Auftrag();
        return fragmenttab1;
    case 1:
        Email fragmenttab2 = new Email();
        return fragmenttab2;
    case 2:
        Fragen fragmenttab3 = new Fragen();
        return fragmenttab3;
    case 3:
        Statistik fragmenttab4 = new Statistik();
        return fragmenttab4;
    }
    return null;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 4;
}
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        return Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.questions);
    case 1:
        return Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.emails);
    case 2:
        return Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.calls);
    case 3:
        return Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.orders);
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
06-11 09:44:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(18290): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-11 09:44:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(18290):    
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f040024
06-11 09:44:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(18290):    at 
android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:1068)
06-11 09:44:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(18290):    at 
android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:1162)
06-11 09:44:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(18290):    at   
com.myappp.sectionapp.SectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(SectionsPagerAdapter.java:41)
06-11 09:44:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(18290):    at   
android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip.updateText(PagerTitleStrip.java:280)
06-11 09:44:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(18290):    at  
android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip.updateAdapter(PagerTitleStrip.java:327)
06-11 09:44:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(18290):    at 
android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip.onAttachedToWindow(PagerTitleStrip.java:256)
06-11 09:44:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(18290):    at 
android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:13029)
06-11 09:44:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(18290):    at 
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2683)
06-11 09:44:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(18290):    at 
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2690)
06-11 09:44:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(18290):    at 
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2690)
06-11 09:44:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(18290):    at 
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2690)
06-11 09:44:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(18290):    at 
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2690)
06-11 09:44:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(18290):    at 
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2690)
06-11 09:44:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(18290):    at  
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1457)
06-11 09:44:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(18290):    at 
android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
06-11 09:44:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(18290):    at 
android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6364)
06-11 09:44:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(18290):    at 
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
06-11 09:44:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(18290):    at 
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
06-11 09:44:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(18290):    at 
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:561)
06-11 09:44:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(18290):    at 
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
06-11 09:44:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(18290):    at 
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
06-11 09:44:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(18290):    at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-11 09:44:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(18290):    at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
06-11 09:44:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(18290):    at  
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
06-11 09:44:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(18290):    at   
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-11 09:44:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(18290):    at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-11 09:44:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(18290):    at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
06-11 09:44:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(18290):    at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
06-11 09:44:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(18290):    at  
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be this:

```
getResources().getString(R.string.my_string);
```

For knowing why you are getting error please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864015/why-cant-i-use-resources-getsystem-without-a-runtime-error) SO post.

Comment: It says: The method getResources is undefined for the type Sectionpageradapter.

Comment: then use context.getResources() something similar must exist for your context

Comment: could you give me some hints for how i define context correctly?

Comment: the best way could be to pass a context to the constructor itself Context context;//this is class variable public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,Context context) {
    super(fm); this.context = context
}