# How do I get a string from string.xml in Java using Android SDK?

Tags: java, android, xml, string

Before I ask, I've already looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183962/how-to-read-value-from-string-xml-in-android) and tried all suggestions to no avail. My problem is that I can easily set a String using

```
getResources().getString(R.string.example)
```

within the onCreate method, but I want to set a public static final String to a value in string.xml using the same getResources() method. But, when I do this, I get a "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getResources() from the type ContextThemeWrapper". So I tried instantiating ContextThemeWrapper and also

```
this.getResources().getString(R.string.example)
```

which both clear the error, but both crash with a NullPointerException. Any solution to simply set a String from a resource would be much appreciated.

So far I have this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ContextThemeWrapper contextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper();
    public final String CYPHER = contextThemeWrapper.getResources().getString(R.string.cypher_txt);
    public static final int LAYERS = 7;
    public static final int FLIP = 3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String appName = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome to " + appName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a static Context object.  For that, you can use the application context.

Assuming your application manifest is as follows:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="my.app.package" ...

      <application android:name=".MyApp" ...
```

1) Create an application class with a public static method to return this context.

```
package my.app.package;  // This should match the package path in your Manifest

public class MyApp extends android.app.Application { // This should match the app name in your manifest

    private static MyApp appContext;

    public MyApp() { appContext = this; }

    public static Context getAppContext() { return appContext; }

}
```

2) Then in your activity, you can make statically obtain the context and resolve the resource:

```
public final String CYPHER = MyApp.getContext().getResources.getString(R.string.cypher_txt);
```

Comment: should be `MyApp extends Application`, the only thing that won't work is switching the device locale when there are multiple language versions of the string since it is loaded just once but never updates.

Comment: So does this approach fix your originally stated question?  Dealing with multiple languages is a different concern that was not in your question.

Comment: As for switching the device locale... the user will have to restart the app in order for string resources to be resolved in the new locale.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me either. I came to the conclusion to just hard-code the string into the java code. Although I would really like to know how to make this work for future reference, even though I'm sure there are more than a few work-arounds for this.

Comment: I cannot see why this would not work.  Any android.app.Context object can get you access to the application resources.  What was your specific problem?

Comment: FWIW, this is a common approach.  I use it in my app without any issues.