# Retrieve string from Strings.xml in C#

Tags: c#, android, xml, string

I am currently working on an interactive book for Android in C# (right now I am doing a test version of it).

I store **strings** in the file **Strings.xml** (default file for strings).

In the **Main.axml** file I created a TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txttest1" />
```

This is just basic stuff to contain my strings where the story would be stored.

In the **Strings.xml** file is a test string:

```
<string name="storytest1">This is where a piece of the story will go, bla bla, once 
upon a time there was our Hero who did this and that...
</string>
```

So in this **TextView** *txttest1* I want to load this string.
In my **MainActivity.cs** file I did this:

```
namespace InteractiveBookTest
{
[Activity (Label = "InteractiveBookTest", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    private TextView mTextView;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        string customstring = "Here I should retrieve storytest1";

        mTextView = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.txttest1);
        mTextView.Text = customstring;
    }
}
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Refer this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183962/how-to-read-value-from-string-xml-in-android)

Comment: I don't know which Directive contains getResources but I cannot seem to find it. The name 'getResources' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Oh I found out that R.string.stringname can be found in Java, but I need this in C#....Or something like that, I'm kind of clueless about this.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution.

```
string customstring = GetString (Resource.String.storytest1);
```

This works. Without the GetString part it gives an error, but with the GetString and referring via Resource.String.stringname (if I get it correctly Resource.String refers to the Strings.xml in the Resources/values folder).