# How to call string from res string.xml?

Tags: android, xml

This is my string.xml. I wanted to call the string name url in the xml.How    should i call it?

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">FinalDemo</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="url">"http://10.207.201.105/apexStore2/"</string>
</resources>
```

This is how i call. However i have been getting error. How should i call it?

```
String ipAddress = getApplicationContext().getString(R.strings.url);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to read value from string.xml in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183962/how-to-read-value-from-string-xml-in-android)

Comment: @Charlene Be sure to remove the quotes in your XML: `<string name="url">http://10.207.201.105/apexStore2/</string>`

Answer (score 1):

Use this Code its work in your case

```
String ipAddress = getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.strings.url);
```

Comment: It say cannot resolve getApplicationContext(). Error in this part

Comment: if you extends Activity then use this.getResources().getString(R.strings.url); else if you extends Fragment then use getActivity().getResources().getString(R.strings.url);

Comment: if you extends Activity then use this.getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.strings.url); else if you extends Fragment then use getActivity().getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.strings.url);

Answer (score 0):

You should call it using

```
String ipAddress = getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.url);
```

See the related documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html)

Answer (score 0):

To learn more: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

```
String url= getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
String ipAddress = getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.strings.url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this....

```
 String ipAddress =getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.url);
```

and for more information:- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Answer (score -1):

in your question. you said in xml but

`String ipAddress = getApplicationContext().getString(R.strings.url);`

is a java code. In xml you can simply do it like this

```
 <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/url" />
```

Also, in your error you should access your resources before the getString method

```
String ipAddress = getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.strings.url);
```

Comment: It say cannot resolve getApplicationContext(). Error in this part