# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()'

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-context

I have a class dedicated to managing sharedpreferences, however I keep getting a NPE on one of my calls. Heres the class,

```
public class UserManager extends Activity{

Context mContext;

UserManager(Context mContext){
    this.mContext = mContext;
}


public boolean getFromMatches(String userUid, String matchUid){
    SharedPreferences spMatches = mContext.getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.match_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(spMatches.contains(userUid + matchUid)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

This is what is passed from my main activity:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);

    userManager = new UserManager(getApplicationContext());
}
```

The NPE is received at this line:

```
SharedPreferences spMatches = mContext.getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.match_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2184151/5515371 check this

Comment: @SpecialSnowflake Use this.mContext instead of mcontext in the line `mContext.getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.match_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

Comment: Are you calling  getFromMatches() before onCreate()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace the `getFromMatches` function with this

```
public boolean getFromMatches(String userUid, String matchUid){
     SharedPreferences spMatches =  mContext.getSharedPreferences(mContext.getString(R.string.match_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     if(spMatches.contains(userUid + matchUid)){
        return true;
     }else{
       return false;
     }
}
```

for calling `getString` or any resources you will need `Context`

Answer (score 0):

**Use this**

```
SharedPreferences spMatches = mContext.getSharedPreferences(getResources().getString(R.string.match_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```