# Android Studio Automatically Erases Extra Spaces In txt Files

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This isn't exactly a programming question, but it's a question specifically about Android Studio.

I am working on a song lyrics app, and I am I have been asked to add the chords to songs, which is what I am doing. So I have the songs formatted in the following way; I have chords on 1 line, and lyrics on the next. In order to have the chords and lyrics show up properly, I need the chord line to be the exact same length as the lyrics line. This usually includes adding a few spaces at the end of the chord line, to match the length. But I noticed that Android Studio automatically erases all the necessary spaces at the end.

Any suggestions on what I could do??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a way to add `spaces` in your `strings.xml` file with **double quotes**. Please refer this [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling)

```
<string name="my_space_string">"    This will work perfectly   "</string>
```

or just use the **UTF Code** to add spaces.

```
<string name="my_space_string">\u0020\u0020This will work perfectly.\u0020\u0020</string>
```

I hope this helps you..

Comment: I almost have no experience with `Strings.xml`, so I dont know how to add a string from `Strings.xml` directly to the `.txt` file

Comment: You can access strings in the strings.xml file from your java code directly. See this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/2184151/4608334 and please refer the official document too https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Comment: Solved your problem ? If my answer helps you then accept it. @Eddie

Answer (score 1):

You may need to replace spaces with the unicode space characters `\u0020`.

For example, `<string name="name">Text\u0020</string>`.

Or as Vinoth has noted, just surround the text with quotation marks and add your spaces.

Comment: That just displays `\u0020`   Literally

Comment: Instead of adding them to the text file, can you store each chord line as a separate string in the strings.xml file, and add these characters there?