# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException when string resource exists

Tags: android, string, resources

I have a few strings which have been put in the android values/strings.xml file in my android project.

```
<resources>
    <string name="level_reached_label">Level Reached: </string>
    <string name="endgame_textP1">You have scored </string>
    <string name="endgame_textP2"> points in </string>
    <string name="endgame_textP3"> seconds </string>
</resources>
```

I call the strings with this line in one of my java classes

```
endLevelLabel.setText(R.string.level_reached_label + level);
endInfoLabel.setText(R.string.endgame_textP1 + score + R.string.endgame_textP2 + gameTime + R.string.endgame_textP3);
```

The first line runs fine but the second line gives this error (the program works with the 2nd line commented out):

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.web.mathtaketwo/com.web.mathtaketwo.EndGame}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7d1500be
```

What did i do wrong that stopped this string from working? Is it because i am trying to use multiple strings in 1 line combined with variables? Why does the other string load fine?

note: the two object that are being set are `TextView`'s:

```
TextView endInfoLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.endInfoLabel);
TextView endLevelLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.endLevelLabel);
```

Comment: R.string.endgame_textP1 is not a string but int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so basically the problem is `R.string.xxx` returns only the ID of a string.

This results in many problems as i try to inserts ID's (integers) into my string.

Instead what i should have done was use the `getString()` function which returns the string at the id specified:

```
getString(R.string.xxxx)
```

If i change my code using `getString()`:

```
endLevelLabel.setText(getString(R.string.level_reached_label) + (level));
endInfoLabel.setText(getString(R.string.endgame_textP1) + score + getString(R.string.endgame_textP2) + gameTime + getString(R.string.endgame_textP3));
```

Then it works correctly. For more details see these other topics which i looked at:

[Reading value from string resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183962/how-to-read-value-from-string-xml-in-android)

[String Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)

[Get string from resource](https://android--code.blogspot.co.nz/2016/03/android-get-string-from-resources-using.html)