# the right way to set text in TextView programmatically

Tags: java, android, string

Is this the right way to set text in `TextView` programmatically?

```
points_txt.setText(R.string.you_have + current_points + R.string.points);`
```

It shows me a ResourcesNotFoundException error for the string while I can see the string in the strings.xml file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
points_txt.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.you_have) + current_points + getResources().getString(R.string.points));
```

Answer (score 1):

You get a `ResourcesNotFoundException` because you're adding `int` values (resource identifiers are mapped to `int` values at compile time) instead of concatenating `String`s.

The sum of the various resource identifiers might even be another valid resource identifier, but that would only happen accidentally. Nevertheless, if you pass an `int` value into `setText()`, the runtime tries to find a string resource by that number. In your case, it failed and so your app crashed.

So you have to get the `String`s first and concatenate them afterwards:

```
points_txt.setText(getString(R.string.you_have) + current_points + getString(R.string.points));
```

Answer (score 1):

`points_txt.setText(R.string.you_have + current_points + R.string.points);`

This is showing "ResourcesNotFoundException" because "R.string.you_have" is an integer value an "current_point" variable also is an int type

`setText()` requires the String type...

to get string value of "R.string.you_have" you can use

```
getResources().getString(R.string.you_have);
points_txt.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.you_have) + current_points + getResources().getString(R.string.points));
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a string from `strings.xml` do this:

```
String you_have = getResources().getString(R.string.you_have);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there but I feel might be behind a few steps but not sure about this since you haven't shared all of your code.

You need to wire in the TextView first between your Java class and XML

```
TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.i.d.textView1)
```

Next is setting the String for the textview

```
tv1.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.you_have) + "current_points" + getResources().getString(R.string.points));
```

You are basically missing the " " marks which are compulsory when you are assigning hardcoded string.

Answer (score 0):

You must firstly parse that resource to string:

```
String string = getString(R.string.yourString);
```

More about that here:
[how to read value from string.xml in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183962/how-to-read-value-from-string-xml-in-android)

So answer for your question will be literally as following:

```
String you_have = getString(R.string.you_have);
String points = getString(R.string.points);

points_txt.setText(you_have + current_points + points);
```