# How to create textview which automatically updates texts with realtime offline

Tags: java, android

I want to create TextView that will automatically update texts in the Activity with realtime. Because I want it to run offline, I will populate the text to be changed with real dates from string-array.

Example of what I'm aiming to build.
***Today is Saturday, 27-06-2020. "Reading of the day" etc.***

Please how do I achieve this. If the process of creating this requires other use of Library order than TextView please teach me. Thanks !

Comment: Look here how to get current date, then display it in textview after formatting.
You can do this in Activity onResume callback https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369682/how-to-get-current-time-and-date-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to get the current local date and the day.
You can get the current date by:

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
String currDate = localDate.format(formatter);
```

and you can get the current day by:

```
DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.from(LocalDate.now());
```

Now your result string would be:

```
String res = "Today is " + dayOfWeek + ", " + currDate + ". \"Reading of the day\"";
```

Now to update the TextView you created before, let say;

```
TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.tv_id);
tv.setText(res);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I want the text to change as well. This wonderful code you gave me shows same text with real time. I want it as the time is changing, the text will equally change to a new text.

Comment: Each new day should invoke the text for the day stored in String.xml

Comment: It will work when the day changes. Now if you want to get the text from strings.xml, check the below link and apply it to your scenario accordingly and if my answer is good to go for you please mark it as answered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183962/how-to-read-value-from-string-xml-in-android

Comment: Thanks for the link. I hope it would be able to update some texts in <item>Second day reading text </item> by tomorrow. If it does not, i hope you will still give me some help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Calendar** class in *java.util* package.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

Comment: what about the "reading of the day..." auto update with LocalDate?

Comment: What do you mean by "reading of the day..."? Please elaborate.

Comment: I am giving instance of TextView to update with LocalDate everyday for intace "reading of the day for day 01 of the week..."   ,   "reading of the day for day 02 of the week..." etc

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know what is meant by "Reading of the day". Please explain.

Comment: Do you mean the day of the week like Saturday Sunday  etc.?

Comment: No. The LocalDate shows that. What I mean is for instance Today is Saturday, 27-06-2020 Today's message is love your neighbor as yourself.

Comment: Then by tomorrow it will change to Today is Sunday,  28-06-2020 Today's message is trust in God who is the creator of universe. After "Today's message is" + "another instance of text" . The second text in quotes is what I want to continually auto update with respect to LocalDate

Comment: Then use LocalDate reference. I don't know about this. Is it some kind of religious thing?

Comment: If LocalDate reference will serve the purpose, how do I use it?

Comment: Or Is there a way to code some custom texts in the calendar so that whenever I call the string result it will update time, date and custom texts?

Comment: I need to set custom texts to update with LocalDate for 365days of the year